# Security Controls Categorization

Tags: research

I'm doing research about Information Security Controls. Considering that the topic is very wide, I would like to organize in macro categories the security controls that can be adopted by an enterprise to reduce the risk of attack.

For example:

- Control Category 1: Vulnerability Assessment
- Control Category 2: Patching
- Control Category 3: Firewall & IPS

Is there any list of security controls or any categorization like this?

Comment: Have you done any research? There are multiple different frameworks. NIST CSF, ISO 27001, ISF GPG, CIS Top 20. There's quite a few.

Comment: I made a change in your question for you by changing "measures" to "controls". If you search "security controls" you will find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several models already designed for you not to think precisely on categorisation of threats, but to create a safe architecture. The worldwide known entity about this is called NIST, who provides a Policy Framework about cibersecurity.

You can check out on [the official site](https://www.nist.gov/cyberframework/framework) but not before getting an intro about NIST [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NIST_Cybersecurity_Framework) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NIST_Enterprise_Architecture_Model) (Wikipedia).

FYI, NIST is recognised worldwide, but it is still a national entity in the USA.

If you find it a little bit heavy, another alternative can be the Ishikawa model which categorises threats by kind and I’m not sure if provides strategical solutions for each sector.

**Ishikawa diagram**
[image: Ishikawa diagram]

I think there is no official site for this, but there is plenty of information about it anywhere.

Comment: Is NIST a worldwide entity?  After all it is the *national* institute of standards and technology

Comment: It isn’t, it is an entity in USA only. But they have a great trajectory, so they are **recognised** worldwide.

Answer (score -1):

I would start with **physical access** control. If an attacker gets a physical access ...

- ... to your office rooms, he *may* find sensitive information that will enable an attack (like your network topology including firewalls, gateways, etc.), or even information about your security policies
- ... to server rooms (if you have servers), he can compromise your hardware, attach his malicious hardware
- ... to your network rooters/switches, network wires or sockets, he can attach malicios devices to your network and e.g. use sniffers and prepare an attack
- etc.

In these cases other measures like patches or firewalls can be ineffective. That's why I would put *physical access* control on the first place.